# Read lines in Python keeping trailing whitespaces

Tags: python, file, whitespace, readline

I need to read a file which has some trailing whitespaces at each line. For example (the • in this example is used to represent a whitespace):

```
dog•••••••
black•cat•
bird••••••
horse••
pig•••••••
```

Each line, except `horse••`, has 10 chars so I have to remove `horse••` from the file.

At the moment I am using following code:

```
  with open(file_path, "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in d:
      print(len(line))
      if len(line) == 11: # 10+1 (+1 is for the \n)
        f.write(line)
  f.truncate()
  return
```

and this prints:

```
4
10
5
6
4
```

How can I include also trailing whitespaces while reading a file in Python?

Comment: Please ensure that whichever editor you're using to edit the file doesn't automatically strip trailing whitespace upon saving.

Comment: Your output data will always have lower or equal length with input, so overwriting existing file is not the best idea, because it could leave unnecessary data. Open another file for output and *(if needed)* replace existing `o_f.writelines(filter(lambda x: len(x.rstrip("\r\n")) == 10, f))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like

```py
with open(file_path, "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in d:
        print(len(line.split()))
        if len(line.split()) == 11:  # 10+1 (+1 is for the \n)
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: You don't need to split line, `len(line)` will work. Also `(+1 is for the \n)` won't always work (`\r\n` on Windows, which is `+2`)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [rdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637312/read-lines-in-python-keeping-trailing-whitespaces#comment117797187_66637312) PyCharm is removing trailing whitespaces from txt files.

The posted code works perfectly.